# php email sending script not sending email

Tags: php, email, send

following is my script for send email inquiry.. the recipient email address was stored in a db called users.. this script will not work properly.. i think the problem is recipient email section.. because when i used a email address instead of $user it will work..

thanx help me

```
<?php
$refno = $HTTP_POST_VARS['refno'];
$proid = $HTTP_POST_VARS['proid'];
$name = $HTTP_POST_VARS['name'];
$email = $HTTP_POST_VARS['email'];
$msg = $HTTP_POST_VARS['msg'];

//connect db and find email address related to id
include 'db_connector.php';
$id=$HTTP_POST_VARS['id'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
$cont=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$user=$cont['user_email'];  

// recipient name
$recipientname = "'".$name."'";

// recipient email
$recipientemail = $user ;


// subject of the email sent to you
$subject = "Inquiry for your advertisement No. (".$refno.")";

// send an autoresponse to the user?
$autoresponse = "no";

// subject of autoresponse
$autosubject = "Thank you for your inquiry!";

// autoresponse message
$automessage = "Thank you for your inquiry.! We'll get back to you shortly.

";

// END OF NECESSARY MODIFICATIONS


$message = "reference number : $refno

$msg

From $name $email 

---"; 


// send mail and print success message
mail($recipientemail,"$subject","$message","From: $recipientname <$email>");

if($autoresponse == "yes") {
$autosubject = stripslashes($autosubject);
$automessage = stripslashes($automessage);
mail($email,"$autosubject","$automessage","From: $recipientname <$recipientemail>");
}

header("Location:index.php");
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Check if you the email address you get from the query is proper.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your query is SQL injectable. Never ever pass a variable coming from a POST request directly into an SQL query. Use `mysql_real_escape()`.

As to your bug: it seems that `$user` does not contain a valid e-mail address. so, the Mysql query is not returning an e-mail address.

Use $_POST rather than $HTTP_POST_VARS.

Switch on error reporting by prepending these two lines to your PHP code:

PHP code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

Run your script again. Do you get any notices or warnings?

If not, try to display your query, by adding

```
die($query);
```

just before the line that has the `mysql_query` command, and then run the query manually (e.g. using PhpMyAdmin or MySQL Query Browser) to see if you are actually getting a result that looks like an e-mail address.

Comment: i changed to $_POST, also i add the error code now there is error on $id=$_POST['id']; line, and there is a valid email id available in the table

error is
Notice: Undefined index: id in /sendinq.php on line 14

Comment: Is line 14 the line in which `$_POST['id']` is referenced? In that case: are you sure you actually have a POST variable called 'id' in your request?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your PHP program.

Check out :

- If the variables contain the supposed values.
- Query is okay and returns result.
- Proper header is set with mail function.
- etc.

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) have a good example to send mail.

Do not use `$HTTP_POST_VARS['name'];` it is deprecated use `$_POST` instead.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys thanx for the help.. i found the error done in my inquiry form.. the id filed hidden outside of the form tag.. therefore the id value will not passed to the sendinq.php. i change it thank now the sendmail option work properly