# PHP 'email sent' but not received

Tags: php, debugging, email, if-statement

Stuck on a simple php mail thing. Can anybody spot where I've gone wrong. Would be happy for any help.

```
<?php
$to = "example@website.co.uk";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
mail($name, $email, $subject, $message);
if(mail($name, $email, $subject, $message)) { 
  echo "E-Mail Sent"; 
} else { 
  echo "There was a problem"; 
}  
?>
```

Comment: For one thing, you're calling `mail()` twice. For another - that's not how you call mail - you're passing the wrong parameters.

Comment: mail() returns true if PHP successfully handed your email over to the outgoing mail delivery system. After that, PHP is completely removed from the process. If the email's lost, ditched as spam, bounced back, etc... that's not PHP's problem. So check your mailserver logs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php email sending script not sending email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370746/php-email-sending-script-not-sending-email)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this instead, it would need spam proofing etc...

```
<?php
     $to      = 'example@example.com';
     $subject = $_POST['subject'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];
     $headers = 'From: contact@yoursite.com';

     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Exactly how does this fix the OP's problem, other than removing the doubled-sending? Basically all you've done is rename the variables used.

Answer (score 2):

The first comment pretty much said it all, if you need a beginner-friendly tutorial of the `mail()` function, you should check out [**PHP Sending E-mails**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp)

```
<?php
$to = "example@website.co.uk";
$name = 'From:'.$_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $name)) { 
  echo "E-Mail Sent"; 
} else { 
  echo "There was a problem"; 
}  
?>
```

Comment: You're still passing `$message` as the `$headers` parameter.